# How to fix the SRC folder in Java Build Path?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have the following source code hierarchy situation :

```
> ProjectRoot
> |-- src/
>      |--- main/
>            |-----java/ 
>                    |-----com/github/myapp
>                                       |------MyAppMainFile
>            |-----ressources/
> pom.xml
```

How to set the Source Folder in the Build Path of Maven Java Project inside Eclipse ?

Comment: folders should be lowercase like `src/main/java`....and Eclipse should automatically use them if you import the project via M2E ...

Comment: sorry abt that, all folders are lowercase, and Eclipse did not automatically recognize them

Comment: Is it really `ressources`, not `resources`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your eclipse did not recognize importing with "Existing maven projects"

Remove the project from eclipse

run the command "mvn eclipse:eclipse"

import again with General > Existing Projects into Workspace

Comment: Not working ... it gives me : src/main/java and src/main/ressources as SRC folders

Comment: In the root of your project, there is a hidden file .claspath, can you post his content?

Comment: well, u were right , m2e fix that the problem comes from lombok instllation thank u